# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que aparezcan las opciones en un select de forma dinámica?

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando que en mi html se carguen las siguientes opciones, generadas en javascript.

HTML:

```
<select id="processSelect" name="process">
</select>
```

Javascript

```
function createOptionsSelectProcess(arrayResponse){
    var html = '';
    var arrayLength = arrayResponse.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        html += '<option value="'+ arrayResponse[i] +'">' + arrayResponse[i] + '</option>';
    }
    document.getElementById("processSelect").innerHTML = html;
}
```

Sin embargo, el resultado que he observado en debug es que las opciones se generan en el select, pero desaparecen al finalizar la ejecución. ¿Alguien sabe cuál puede ser el motivo?

Comment: Al no mostrar el contexto completo de tu programa es imposible decir por qué el código no funciona de la forma esperado. Dices que *las opciones se generan en el select, pero desaparecen al finalizar la ejecución*, ¿qué significa eso exactamente?  ¿Qué código o función es llamada que hace desaparecer las opciones que se acaban de agregar?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar las herramientas para manejar las opciones de un select para rellenarlo.

```
var arrayLength = arrayResponse.length;
var miselect = document.getElementById("processSelect");
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var option = new Option(arrayResponse[i],i);
    miselect.options.add(option);   
}
```